# How to add a command to Jupyter Notebook toolbar in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My default Jupyter Notebook toolbar in VS Code has a command "Clear Outputs of All Cells". I would like to add a similar but different command `Notebook: Clear Cell Outputs`, which only clears one cell at a time. I can do that by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, but it would be convenient to have it in toolbar.

Comment: is this menu available in `package.json` to add a menu command/button in an extension, if yes you can make this extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this button to the [Context Menu Extra](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.context-menu-extra) extension (v0.4.0) (You need VSC v1.62, because I don't know when some experimental API got public)

If the cell has output you should see the "Clear Cell Output" button in the cell toolbar at first position.

There is no documentation of the allowed groups for this menu. I have used a group the Jupyter extensions also uses. That is the reason it is one of the first buttons.

Comment: I installed this extension and input 
context-menu-extra.notebookClearCell in Terminal, 
but it returns 
zsh: command not found: context-menu-extra.notebookClearCell
My VS code version is the latest. Any idea what's causing it? Thanks

Comment: it is a VSC command, you do not have to execute it, I have to create a VSC command to bind it to a menu option, Just create a notebook and create a cell and execute it and then the button appears in the cell toolbar, You can execute the VSC command from the Command Palette `Ctrl+P` but that is not needed.

Comment: Thanks.My context menu now has Clear Output of Cell. Is there a way to also display it in toolbar right above the first cell of a notebook?

Comment: @c78250125 Try v0.5.0, configure show of buttons with settings